# UniformGrid reduce spacing between rows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, uniformgrid

I am using a WPF UniformGrid to bind alist  of items and the xaml is like this

```
 <ListBox  Name="lviewSearch"  ItemsSource="{Binding SearchSettingsCollection}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl Margin="3" Padding="5">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Label}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Cursor="Hand" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

But if the no of items is less then the spacing between rows is too much like this 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr5qy.png

How can i ireduce thi s?

Answer (score 7):

Like people said, your UniformGrid has too much vertical space so it expands the rows to take up all that space (stretches).

What you need to do is prevent this default behavior of stretching by setting

```
VerticalAlignment="Top"
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the **UniformGrid** is that the size of cells is uniform and therefore the same size. If you only have a small number of rows compared to the vertical space then each row is going to be pretty tall. Conversely if you have many rows and little vertical space then each row becomes tiny. If this is not an appropriate appearance then you need to use a different method of laying out.

Without knowing much more about the visual design it becomes impossible to recommend a possible alternative. Is the ListBox always the same size or will it vary in height? Does the number of displayed results vary or stay constant? All these change how you might achieve the required result.

Comment: The number of displayed results is going to be fixed only most if the cases.Even a small chance of adding or removing few items is there

Comment: You could add dummy entries that do not display any output so that the number of list entries forces each cell to be much smaller. Harder work to implement though.

Comment: Is there any alternate option to achieve the same ? If i use ItemsControl i cant get the effect of ListBoxItem selection . Otherwise i can use a WrapPanel inside ItemsControl . BUt here it is also out of scope

Comment: You can use a WrapPanel inside the ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use grid outside Listbox. Set row height as auto. Now Uniform grid will take minimum space as required.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<ListBox Name="lviewSearch"  ItemsSource="{Binding SearchSettingsCollection}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl Margin="3" Padding="5">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Label}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Cursor="Hand" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
</Grid>
```